# android - call a url dynamically from the background in 2 seconds

Tags: java, android

I have a url in an android application that fetches data from an async task as shown below

```
 new AsyncParam().execute("http://10.0.2.2:88/API/web/app_dev.php/get/1/7");
```

Please how can I ensure that the above url is called dynamically every one seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use this:
//Declare globally

Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable;

//then whereever you want to call your url
runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AsyncParam().execute("http://10.0.2.2:88/API/web/app_dev.php/get/1/7");
//this will call your url after every one sec
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
            }
        };
//in place of 1000 provide initial delay you can give 0 also if you want to call immediately
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
```

Comment: do I have to create a method to use this. pasting it in oncreate method throws exceoptions

Comment: what exception are you getting

Comment: variable handler is accessed from within inner class and needs to declared final

Comment: handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);

Comment: The first two line Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable; write above your oncreate. you'll be fine

Comment: is there a way I can refresh the state of an activity within a 2 seconds

Comment: refresh state of activity means??

Comment: yes every two seconds but it should not distort the view

Comment: I didn't understand your question what do you mean by refreshing the state of activity. Do you want to call the url after every two seconds instead of one?? or something else you are trying to say here

Comment: kind of reloading an activity just as when u launch it using intents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146245/discussion-between-sumit-and-parker).